# Play WAV audio files in Android's Exoplayer

Tags: android, audio, wav, exoplayer, extractor

I implemented my Exoplayer and I'm playing songs using this code:

```
    Allocator allocator = new DefaultAllocator(BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
    DataSource dataSource = new DefaultUriDataSource(mService, null, "useragent");
    ExtractorSampleSource sampleSource = new ExtractorSampleSource(Uri.parse(url), dataSource, allocator, BUFFER_SEGMENT_COUNT * BUFFER_SEGMENT_SIZE);
    MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer audioRenderer = new MediaCodecAudioTrackRenderer(sampleSource, MediaCodecSelector.DEFAULT);
    mExoPlayer.prepare(audioRenderer);
```

I want to play not only MP3 audio files, but also WAV files. I read that I should create my custom Extractor but I really can not find any documentation for it.

Does anybody know how can I play WAV audio files in my Exoplayer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this : https://github.com/google/ExoPlayer/issues/1246

Might be implemented in future releases

Comment: Thank you but it's me who created that issue :).

Comment: Ahah. Ok :) Well then we just have to wait

Comment: Hey guys I wanted to know if how the playerview can be hidden when streaming audio with no artwork...I want to hide the black screen or have it wrap around the controls